# Plotting Conditionally Summed Data (base R or ggplot)

Tags: r, ggplot2

I started with a dataframe containing info on West Nile cases in Canada from 2012-2015.  600 observations of 10 variables in total.

```
> head(mosquitoes)
  Years Weeks Province Avg.Temp Avg..Precepitation Wind Number.of.cases Number.of.Dead.Birds Mosquito.Pools.Tested Google.Trend.Searches
1  2015    17  Alberta       48               0.01    8               0                    0                     0                     1
2  2015    18  Alberta       46               0.03   10               0                    0                     0                     2
3  2015    19  Alberta       44               0.07    8               0                    0                     0                     2
4  2015    20  Alberta       51               0.00    9               0                    0                     0                     2
5  2015    21  Alberta       56               0.01    9               0                    0                     0                     4
6  2015    22  Alberta       58               0.10    7               0                    0                     0                     1
```

Here is the entire data set....sorry it's large.

```
Years,Weeks,Province,Avg Temp ,Avg. Precepitation,Wind,Number of cases,Number of Dead Birds,Mosquito Pools Tested,Google Trend Searches
2015,17,Alberta,48,0.01,8,0,0,0,1
2015,18,Alberta,46,0.03,10,0,0,0,2
2015,19,Alberta,44,0.07,8,0,0,0,2
2015,20,Alberta,51,0,9,0,0,0,2
2015,21,Alberta,56,0.01,9,0,0,0,4
2015,22,Alberta,58,0.1,7,0,0,0,1
2015,23,Alberta,61,0.05,8,0,0,0,1
2015,24,Alberta,55,0.08,9,0,0,0,1
2015,25,Alberta,63,0.02,6,0,0,0,4
2015,26,Alberta,67,0.16,8,0,0,0,5
2015,27,Alberta,65,0.02,8,0,0,0,3
2015,28,Alberta,62,0.09,10,0,0,0,7
2015,29,Alberta,66,0.01,8,0,0,0,2
2015,30,Alberta,62,0.02,7,0,0,0,3
2015,31,Alberta,64,0.21,7,0,0,0,6
2015,32,Alberta,66,0.07,7,0,0,0,4
2015,33,Alberta,55,0.13,8,0,0,0,4
2015,34,Alberta,63,0,6,0,0,0,1
2015,35,Alberta,52,0.11,9,0,0,0,4
2015,36,Alberta,54,0.02,7,0,0,0,2
2015,37,Alberta,48,0.06,8,0,0,0,2
2015,38,Alberta,52,0.03,9,0,0,0,3
2015,39,Alberta,49,0.03,9,0,0,0,3
2015,40,Alberta,51,0,8,0,0,0,2
2015,41,Alberta,48,0,8,0,0,0,2
2014,17,Alberta,43,0.05,8,0,0,0,1
2014,18,Alberta,44,0.06,9,0,0,0,3
2014,19,Alberta,37,0.03,9,0,0,0,3
2014,20,Alberta,48,0.01,8,0,0,0,1
2014,21,Alberta,57,0.01,10,0,0,0,2
2014,22,Alberta,53,0.06,8,0,0,0,4
2014,23,Alberta,53,0.04,10,0,0,0,6
2014,24,Alberta,53,0.04,10,0,0,0,6
2014,25,Alberta,54,0.24,9,0,0,0,4
2014,26,Alberta,59,0.03,9,0,0,0,7
2014,27,Alberta,64,0.02,11,0,0,0,19
2014,28,Alberta,65,0.03,10,0,0,0,33
2014,29,Alberta,67,0.01,9,0,0,0,18
2014,30,Alberta,62,0.08,10,0,0,0,14
2014,31,Alberta,68,0,10,0,0,0,10
2014,32,Alberta,63,0.16,8,0,0,0,11
2014,33,Alberta,66,0.01,7,0,0,0,19
2014,34,Alberta,58,0.05,8,0,0,0,17
2014,35,Alberta,58,0.04,7,0,0,0,8
2014,36,Alberta,54,0.01,7,0,0,0,12
2014,37,Alberta,41,0.15,8,0,0,0,3
2014,38,Alberta,58,0,5,0,0,0,3
2014,39,Alberta,60,0.02,6,0,0,0,4
2014,40,Alberta,48,0.03,11,0,0,0,5
2014,41,Alberta,51,0,6,0,0,0,3
2013,17,Alberta,42,0,12,0,0,0,3
2013,18,Alberta,42,0.01,11,0,0,0,2
2013,19,Alberta,57,0,11,0,0,0,2
2013,20,Alberta,55,0.01,10,0,0,0,9
2013,21,Alberta,50,0.23,11,0,0,0,7
2013,22,Alberta,52,0.08,6,0,0,0,8
2013,23,Alberta,55,0.15,10,0,0,0,10
2013,24,Alberta,53,0.08,10,0,0,0,4
2013,25,Alberta,57,0.3,11,0,0,0,9
2013,26,Alberta,61,0.01,9,0,0,0,17
2013,27,Alberta,65,0.08,10,0,0,0,27
2013,28,Alberta,59,0.07,8,0,0,0,19
2013,29,Alberta,62,0.01,10,0,0,0,21
2013,30,Alberta,62,0.06,10,0,0,0,18
2013,31,Alberta,57,0.03,7,0,0,0,13
2013,32,Alberta,60,0.07,8,0,0,0,10
2013,33,Alberta,67,0,8,3,0,0,2
2013,34,Alberta,63,0,8,5,0,0,12
2013,35,Alberta,64,0.03,10,4,0,0,20
2013,36,Alberta,64,0.13,8,2,1,0,15
2013,37,Alberta,63,0,9,5,0,0,9
2013,38,Alberta,57,0.06,11,2,0,0,11
2013,39,Alberta,47,0,10,0,0,0,4
2013,40,Alberta,44,0,11,0,0,0,5
2013,41,Alberta,45,0.06,8,0,0,0,5
2012,17,Alberta,49,0.06,7,0,0,0,2
2012,18,Alberta,42,0.13,9,0,0,0,2
2012,19,Alberta,48,0,9,0,0,0,6
2012,20,Alberta,53,0.01,10,0,0,0,2
2012,21,Alberta,49,0.08,8,0,0,0,2
2012,22,Alberta,52,0,9,0,0,0,2
2012,23,Alberta,54,0.28,9,0,0,0,4
2012,24,Alberta,56,0.21,12,0,0,0,7
2012,25,Alberta,56,0.05,8,0,0,0,5
2012,26,Alberta,59,0.14,8,0,0,0,3
2012,27,Alberta,61,0.21,9,0,0,0,22
2012,28,Alberta,69,0,8,0,0,0,32
2012,29,Alberta,65,0.09,10,0,0,0,16
2012,30,Alberta,64,0.02,10,0,0,0,15
2012,31,Alberta,63,0.03,10,0,0,0,20
2012,32,Alberta,68,0,10,0,0,0,25
2012,33,Alberta,62,0.07,10,4,0,0,36
2012,34,Alberta,62,0.05,10,2,0,0,100
2012,35,Alberta,61,0.01,10,0,0,0,76
2012,36,Alberta,57,0,12,1,0,0,29
2012,37,Alberta,57,0,12,2,0,0,30
2012,38,Alberta,59,0,9,0,0,0,14
2012,39,Alberta,58,0.01,9,0,0,0,11
2012,40,Alberta,43,0.07,12,0,0,0,10
2012,41,Alberta,43,0.02,13,0,0,0,7
2015,17,British Columbia,53,0.03,10,0,0,0,5
2015,18,British Columbia,53,0.01,6,0,0,0,5
2015,19,British Columbia,58,0.01,7,0,0,0,5
2015,20,British Columbia,60,0,7,0,0,0,4
2015,21,British Columbia,62,0,7,0,0,0,6
2015,22,British Columbia,60,0.03,7,0,0,0,9
2015,23,British Columbia,62,0,13,0,0,0,9
2015,24,British Columbia,62,0.02,8,0,0,0,10
2015,25,British Columbia,66,0,9,0,0,0,7
2015,26,British Columbia,70,0,12,0,0,0,5
2015,27,British Columbia,67,0.01,9,0,0,0,11
2015,28,British Columbia,66,0,10,0,0,0,9
2015,29,British Columbia,65,0.04,9,0,0,0,14
2015,30,British Columbia,65,0.04,6,0,0,0,7
2015,31,British Columbia,65,0.02,9,0,0,0,7
2015,32,British Columbia,66,0.04,9,0,0,0,9
2015,33,British Columbia,65,0,9,0,0,0,11
2015,34,British Columbia,64,0.1,7,0,0,0,6
2015,35,British Columbia,57,0.12,10,0,0,0,4
2015,36,British Columbia,61,0.02,9,0,0,0,9
2015,37,British Columbia,58,0.09,9,0,0,0,9
2015,38,British Columbia,55,0.04,9,0,0,0,3
2015,39,British Columbia,52,0,6,0,0,0,3
2015,40,British Columbia,56,0.08,6,0,0,0,3
2015,41,British Columbia,51,0.04,7,0,0,0,7
2014,17,British Columbia,49,0.07,10,0,0,0,3
2014,18,British Columbia,54,0.03,8,0,0,0,4
2014,19,British Columbia,53,0.18,9,0,0,0,4
2014,20,British Columbia,60,0,8,0,0,0,6
2014,21,British Columbia,59,0.06,7,0,0,0,6
2014,22,British Columbia,56,0.09,7,0,0,0,6
2014,23,British Columbia,59,0,8,0,0,0,8
2014,24,British Columbia,60,0.03,10,0,0,0,7
2014,25,British Columbia,58,0.09,9,0,0,0,8
2014,26,British Columbia,62,0.05,7,0,0,0,10
2014,27,British Columbia,64,0.01,8,0,0,0,7
2014,28,British Columbia,66,0.01,8,0,0,0,19
2014,29,British Columbia,68,0,9,0,0,0,13
2014,30,British Columbia,63,0.06,8,0,0,0,12
2014,31,British Columbia,67,0,6,0,0,0,16
2014,32,British Columbia,66,0,7,0,0,0,25
2014,33,British Columbia,67,0.08,7,0,0,0,17
2014,34,British Columbia,65,0,6,0,0,0,13
2014,35,British Columbia,66,0,7,0,0,0,30
2014,36,British Columbia,61,0.05,7,0,0,0,9
2014,37,British Columbia,60,0,6,0,0,0,11
2014,38,British Columbia,61,0.02,6,0,0,0,3
2014,39,British Columbia,62,0.12,9,0,0,0,8
2014,40,British Columbia,56,0.04,6,0,0,0,9
2014,41,British Columbia,58,0.03,5,0,0,0,7
2013,17,British Columbia,50,0.03,7,0,0,0,14
2013,18,British Columbia,50,0,12,0,0,0,8
2013,19,British Columbia,59,0.03,6,0,0,0,5
2013,20,British Columbia,56,0.07,8,0,0,0,7
2013,21,British Columbia,54,0.04,8,0,0,0,4
2013,22,British Columbia,55,0.09,7,0,0,0,8
2013,23,British Columbia,60,0.01,9,0,0,0,14
2013,24,British Columbia,58,0.01,7,0,0,0,16
2013,25,British Columbia,62,0.04,8,0,0,0,10
2013,26,British Columbia,63,0.1,7,0,0,0,17
2013,27,British Columbia,67,0,8,0,0,0,29
2013,28,British Columbia,63,0,8,0,0,0,30
2013,29,British Columbia,66,0,9,0,0,0,20
2013,30,British Columbia,64,0,8,0,0,0,34
2013,31,British Columbia,64,0.02,8,0,0,0,11
2013,32,British Columbia,66,0,6,0,0,1,13
2013,33,British Columbia,66,0.02,8,0,0,1,16
2013,34,British Columbia,63,0.01,8,0,0,1,16
2013,35,British Columbia,65,0.17,7,0,1,1,12
2013,36,British Columbia,64,0.06,6,0,0,1,8
2013,37,British Columbia,63,0,6,0,0,1,14
2013,38,British Columbia,60,0.19,6,0,0,1,6
2013,39,British Columbia,54,0.23,10,0,0,1,6
2013,40,British Columbia,51,0.15,9,0,0,1,6
2013,41,British Columbia,51,0.01,8,0,0,1,8
2012,17,British Columbia,53,0.05,8,0,0,0,5
2012,18,British Columbia,50,0.11,7,0,0,0,6
2012,19,British Columbia,52,0,9,0,0,0,7
2012,20,British Columbia,54,0,10,0,0,0,8
2012,21,British Columbia,55,0.06,8,0,0,0,9
2012,22,British Columbia,57,0.07,7,0,0,0,8
2012,23,British Columbia,53,0.07,8,0,0,0,4
2012,24,British Columbia,57,0.04,8,0,0,0,4
2012,25,British Columbia,58,0.13,8,0,0,0,7
2012,26,British Columbia,60,0.04,8,0,0,0,8
2012,27,British Columbia,59,0.03,7,0,0,0,22
2012,28,British Columbia,66,0,6,0,0,0,30
2012,29,British Columbia,66,0.05,8,0,0,0,30
2012,30,British Columbia,63,0.03,8,0,0,0,38
2012,31,British Columbia,65,0,8,0,0,0,60
2012,32,British Columbia,67,0.01,8,0,0,0,34
2012,33,British Columbia,69,0,7,0,0,0,63
2012,34,British Columbia,63,0,8,0,0,0,100
2012,35,British Columbia,62,0,7,0,0,0,51
2012,36,British Columbia,62,0,7,0,0,0,32
2012,37,British Columbia,58,0.01,8,0,0,0,24
2012,38,British Columbia,60,0,6,0,0,0,13
2012,39,British Columbia,57,0,6,0,0,0,13
2012,40,British Columbia,53,0,8,0,0,0,6
2012,41,British Columbia,52,0.09,5,0,0,0,8
2015,17,Manitoba,56,0,10,0,0,0,4
2015,18,Manitoba,48,0,13,0,0,0,4
2015,19,Manitoba,46,0,10,0,0,0,4
2015,20,Manitoba,52,0,14,0,0,0,4
2015,21,Manitoba,57,0,10,0,0,12,4
2015,22,Manitoba,60,0,12,0,0,4,8
2015,23,Manitoba,67,0,9,0,0,87,8
2015,24,Manitoba,59,0,9,0,0,82,8
2015,25,Manitoba,66,0,7,0,0,44,8
2015,26,Manitoba,68,0,7,0,0,75,11
2015,27,Manitoba,66,0,10,0,0,73,17
2015,28,Manitoba,70,0,7,0,0,132,8
2015,29,Manitoba,69,0,9,0,0,139,17
2015,30,Manitoba,70,0,11,0,0,204,4
2015,31,Manitoba,63,0,9,0,0,275,13
2015,32,Manitoba,73,0,9,0,0,195,23
2015,33,Manitoba,62,0,10,0,0,228,13
2015,34,Manitoba,62,0,11,0,0,69,12
2015,35,Manitoba,73,0,11,1,0,92,10
2015,36,Manitoba,57,0,10,1,0,113,8
2015,37,Manitoba,60,0,11,2,0,34,4
2015,38,Manitoba,61,0,13,1,0,0,4
2015,39,Manitoba,53,0,13,0,0,0,6
2015,40,Manitoba,48,0,11,0,0,0,6
2015,41,Manitoba,44,0,11,0,0,0,6
2014,17,Manitoba,42,0,11,0,0,0,4
2014,18,Manitoba,42,0,14,0,0,0,0
2014,19,Manitoba,46,0,9,0,0,0,0
2014,20,Manitoba,45,0,10,0,0,0,0
2014,21,Manitoba,57,0,12,0,0,0,0
2014,22,Manitoba,66,0,8,0,0,0,0
2014,23,Manitoba,62,0,10,0,0,0,5
2014,24,Manitoba,60,0,11,0,0,0,13
2014,25,Manitoba,62,0,12,0,0,0,9
2014,26,Manitoba,66,0,10,0,0,0,7
2014,27,Manitoba,65,0,15,0,0,0,9
2014,28,Manitoba,67,0,11,0,0,0,36
2014,29,Manitoba,63,0,11,0,0,0,24
2014,30,Manitoba,68,0,9,0,0,0,53
2014,31,Manitoba,65,0,8,0,0,7,41
2014,32,Manitoba,71,0,8,0,0,7,48
2014,33,Manitoba,68,0,8,1,0,14,14
2014,34,Manitoba,67,0,8,2,0,19,18
2014,35,Manitoba,61,0,11,2,0,22,9
2014,36,Manitoba,60,0,8,0,0,24,4
2014,37,Manitoba,50,0,11,0,0,24,11
2014,38,Manitoba,52,0,10,0,0,24,4
2014,39,Manitoba,65,0,13,0,0,24,15
2014,40,Manitoba,47,0,16,0,0,24,4
2014,41,Manitoba,39,0,13,0,0,24,4
2013,17,Manitoba,36,0.01,12,0,0,0,4
2013,18,Manitoba,38,0.11,9,0,0,0,4
2013,19,Manitoba,49,0.02,12,0,0,0,4
2013,20,Manitoba,56,0.02,10,0,0,0,5
2013,21,Manitoba,55,0.05,14,0,0,0,4
2013,22,Manitoba,58,0.16,15,0,0,0,4
2013,23,Manitoba,57,0.01,9,0,0,0,9
2013,24,Manitoba,63,0.03,10,0,0,0,16
2013,25,Manitoba,66,0.1,9,0,0,0,23
2013,26,Manitoba,69,0.24,10,0,0,0,14
2013,27,Manitoba,72,0,6,0,0,0,23
2013,28,Manitoba,70,0.06,10,0,0,1,19
2013,29,Manitoba,66,0.1,9,0,0,1,45
2013,30,Manitoba,60,0.19,8,0,1,7,35
2013,31,Manitoba,61,0.03,7,0,0,10,31
2013,32,Manitoba,59,0.04,7,0,0,16,22
2013,33,Manitoba,64,0.02,8,1,0,16,24
2013,34,Manitoba,71,0.17,10,0,0,16,49
2013,35,Manitoba,76,0.01,7,0,0,17,14
2013,36,Manitoba,64,0,10,1,0,17,11
2013,37,Manitoba,63,0.01,8,0,0,19,9
2013,38,Manitoba,54,0,11,0,0,19,6
2013,39,Manitoba,60,0.1,12,0,0,19,13
2013,40,Manitoba,50,0.03,11,0,0,19,8
2013,41,Manitoba,52,0,10,0,1,19,4
2012,17,Manitoba,46,0.01,12,0,0,0,0
2012,18,Manitoba,51,0.05,11,0,0,0,0
2012,19,Manitoba,56,0.06,13,0,0,0,5
2012,20,Manitoba,58,0.16,12,0,0,0,6
2012,21,Manitoba,53,0.02,11,0,0,0,5
2012,22,Manitoba,53,0.13,9,0,0,0,5
2012,23,Manitoba,67,0.08,8,0,0,0,8
2012,24,Manitoba,62,0.17,11,0,0,0,10
2012,25,Manitoba,60,0.04,8,0,0,0,11
2012,26,Manitoba,68,0,10,0,0,0,11
2012,27,Manitoba,73,0.03,7,0,0,0,15
2012,28,Manitoba,73,0,7,0,0,0,17
2012,29,Manitoba,69,0.05,8,1,0,2,21
2012,30,Manitoba,71,0,8,1,0,20,36
2012,31,Manitoba,71,0.2,9,4,0,48,100
2012,32,Manitoba,67,0,9,7,0,62,47
2012,33,Manitoba,62,0.04,8,7,0,98,31
2012,34,Manitoba,69,0.01,7,6,0,108,84
2012,35,Manitoba,70,0.01,11,7,0,111,75
2012,36,Manitoba,63,0.01,11,1,0,116,22
2012,37,Manitoba,59,0.01,11,3,0,116,23
2012,38,Manitoba,47,0.01,12,2,0,116,13
2012,39,Manitoba,50,0,8,0,0,116,5
2012,40,Manitoba,46,0.02,15,0,0,116,7
2012,41,Manitoba,37,0.02,10,0,0,116,5
2015,17,Quebec,53,0,8,0,0,0,8
2015,18,Quebec,65,0.06,8,0,0,0,8
2015,19,Quebec,58,0.09,10,0,0,0,8
2015,20,Quebec,59,0.05,11,0,0,0,8
2015,21,Quebec,69,0.11,11,0,0,0,8
2015,22,Quebec,56,0.07,9,0,0,0,8
2015,23,Quebec,65,0.16,9,0,0,0,8
2015,24,Quebec,64,0.16,7,0,0,0,16
2015,25,Quebec,67,0.18,8,0,0,0,8
2015,26,Quebec,64,0.07,9,0,0,120,19
2015,27,Quebec,71,0.01,8,0,0,127,24
2015,28,Quebec,70,0.05,9,0,1,132,24
2015,29,Quebec,70,0.3,8,0,1,131,16
2015,30,Quebec,75,0.07,9,1,2,129,16
2015,31,Quebec,67,0.02,9,1,3,126,8
2015,32,Quebec,69,0.31,7,0,0,133,8
2015,33,Quebec,76,0.11,9,1,1,125,16
2015,34,Quebec,68,0.01,8,2,1,123,11
2015,35,Quebec,70,0,8,1,3,131,31
2015,36,Quebec,72,0.15,8,2,4,128,15
2015,37,Quebec,69,0.21,9,6,0,123,7
2015,38,Quebec,58,0,7,5,0,108,7
2015,39,Quebec,55,0.17,11,2,2,107,11
2015,40,Quebec,49,0.03,7,5,0,0,7
2015,41,Quebec,51,0.11,11,8,0,0,15
2014,17,Quebec,46,0.05,9,0,0,0,0
2014,18,Quebec,49,0.18,12,0,0,0,0
2014,19,Quebec,53,0.09,10,0,0,0,0
2014,20,Quebec,62,0.17,13,0,0,0,0
2014,21,Quebec,59,0.01,9,0,0,0,13
2014,22,Quebec,59,0.08,9,0,0,0,13
2014,23,Quebec,66,0.13,8,0,0,0,40
2014,24,Quebec,66,0.28,11,0,0,0,18
2014,25,Quebec,65,0.14,8,0,0,0,27
2014,26,Quebec,69,0.14,6,0,0,0,33
2014,27,Quebec,75,0.02,9,0,0,0,23
2014,28,Quebec,70,0.08,12,0,0,0,40
2014,29,Quebec,69,0.05,9,0,0,1,27
2014,30,Quebec,72,0.06,10,0,0,4,28
2014,31,Quebec,66,0.18,8,0,0,9,54
2014,32,Quebec,70,0.04,6,0,0,10,24
2014,33,Quebec,67,0.2,10,1,2,19,34
2014,34,Quebec,66,0,7,1,0,19,9
2014,35,Quebec,70,0,8,1,1,39,17
2014,36,Quebec,72,0.11,10,1,0,70,8
2014,37,Quebec,60,0.12,9,0,3,99,12
2014,38,Quebec,52,0.02,9,1,2,112,13
2014,39,Quebec,61,0.02,9,0,0,119,15
2014,40,Quebec,58,0.06,11,0,1,119,16
2014,41,Quebec,51,0.1,13,1,0,119,16
2013,17,Quebec,46,0.03,11,1,0,0,9
2013,18,Quebec,60,0.01,7,0,0,0,9
2013,19,Quebec,65,0.08,8,0,0,0,9
2013,20,Quebec,51,0.01,11,0,0,0,18
2013,21,Quebec,64,0.19,10,0,0,0,17
2013,22,Quebec,64,0.18,9,0,0,0,9
2013,23,Quebec,59,0.11,10,0,0,0,21
2013,24,Quebec,64,0.11,9,0,0,0,18
2013,25,Quebec,62,0.09,8,0,0,0,9
2013,26,Quebec,69,0.14,9,0,0,0,37
2013,27,Quebec,72,0.02,9,0,0,0,9
2013,28,Quebec,73,0.06,8,0,0,0,45
2013,29,Quebec,79,0.28,9,0,0,2,49
2013,30,Quebec,66,0.06,7,0,0,3,73
2013,31,Quebec,70,0.12,9,1,3,5,40
2013,32,Quebec,68,0.04,9,3,2,11,74
2013,33,Quebec,66,0.08,9,8,4,23,56
2013,34,Quebec,69,0.02,10,3,5,36,64
2013,35,Quebec,70,0.06,7,4,9,36,29
2013,36,Quebec,63,0.06,10,2,6,40,32
2013,37,Quebec,62,0.18,8,3,4,47,20
2013,38,Quebec,58,0.12,9,1,2,59,8
2013,39,Quebec,54,0.03,6,1,0,60,16
2013,40,Quebec,61,0,6,1,0,60,24
2013,41,Quebec,55,0.11,10,0,0,60,20
2012,17,Quebec,40,0.17,13,0,0,0,0
2012,18,Quebec,50,0.03,7,0,0,0,10
2012,19,Quebec,55,0.07,8,0,0,0,10
2012,20,Quebec,61,0.02,7,0,0,0,10
2012,21,Quebec,69,0.1,7,0,0,0,11
2012,22,Quebec,62,0.16,8,0,0,0,10
2012,23,Quebec,61,0.02,8,0,0,0,10
2012,24,Quebec,68,0.08,7,0,0,0,11
2012,25,Quebec,76,0.01,9,0,0,0,11
2012,26,Quebec,69,0.13,9,0,0,0,26
2012,27,Quebec,73,0.12,6,0,0,0,40
2012,28,Quebec,72,0,8,0,2,0,24
2012,29,Quebec,71,0.21,6,1,0,0,11
2012,30,Quebec,71,0.1,7,1,0,0,11
2012,31,Quebec,76,0.01,7,0,1,5,78
2012,32,Quebec,72,0.17,10,2,5,8,31
2012,33,Quebec,70,0.02,7,6,2,19,94
2012,34,Quebec,70,0,6,10,5,19,100
2012,35,Quebec,71,0.01,11,9,8,19,76
2012,36,Quebec,71,0.11,6,14,1,19,70
2012,37,Quebec,63,0.07,8,23,6,19,43
2012,38,Quebec,58,0.12,10,16,0,19,34
2012,39,Quebec,54,0.01,9,27,0,19,38
2012,40,Quebec,57,0.16,8,11,0,19,14
2012,41,Quebec,45,0.06,10,8,0,19,19
2015,17,Ontario,53,0,9,0,0,0,2
2015,18,Ontario,61,0.04,5,0,0,0,2
2015,19,Ontario,58,0.07,7,0,0,0,4
2015,20,Ontario,58,0,8,0,0,0,5
2015,21,Ontario,70,0.11,8,0,0,0,8
2015,22,Ontario,57,0.14,7,0,0,180,8
2015,23,Ontario,65,0.18,6,0,0,356,5
2015,24,Ontario,65,0.08,5,0,1,852,5
2015,25,Ontario,67,0.33,7,0,0,886,13
2015,26,Ontario,63,0.02,7,0,0,954,15
2015,27,Ontario,68,0.04,5,0,0,1152,13
2015,28,Ontario,67,0.03,6,1,0,1216,21
2015,29,Ontario,72,0.01,7,1,4,1219,16
2015,30,Ontario,76,0.03,6,1,1,1222,22
2015,31,Ontario,68,0.06,6,0,8,1176,24
2015,32,Ontario,69,0.21,6,0,0,1168,15
2015,33,Ontario,73,0.09,5,1,0,1168,24
2015,34,Ontario,64,0.01,5,5,1,987,12
2015,35,Ontario,75,0,5,2,1,881,18
2015,36,Ontario,70,0.11,5,5,0,802,9
2015,37,Ontario,65,0.07,6,1,2,712,6
2015,38,Ontario,60,0,5,5,4,526,4
2015,39,Ontario,55,0.04,9,2,2,396,6
2015,40,Ontario,53,0.14,6,3,0,65,5
2015,41,Ontario,52,0.04,8,3,4,0,2
2014,17,Ontario,46,0.05,8,0,0,0,3
2014,18,Ontario,47,0.14,9,0,0,0,2
2014,19,Ontario,53,0,9,0,0,0,2
2014,20,Ontario,56,0.13,6,0,0,0,3
2014,21,Ontario,57,0.09,5,0,0,0,4
2014,22,Ontario,65,0.02,6,0,0,0,7
2014,23,Ontario,63,0.04,6,0,0,0,10
2014,24,Ontario,65,0.19,6,0,0,0,16
2014,25,Ontario,66,0.16,5,0,0,0,13
2014,26,Ontario,69,0.06,4,0,0,0,7
2014,27,Ontario,72,0.09,7,0,0,0,20
2014,28,Ontario,68,0.12,6,0,0,0,17
2014,29,Ontario,66,0.21,5,1,0,0,13
2014,30,Ontario,68,0.03,5,0,0,2,14
2014,31,Ontario,67,0.35,5,0,0,5,35
2014,32,Ontario,68,0.21,4,0,0,9,22
2014,33,Ontario,65,0.12,7,2,0,11,30
2014,34,Ontario,67,0.02,4,0,2,13,11
2014,35,Ontario,67,0,6,2,3,30,18
2014,36,Ontario,71,0.39,5,5,0,43,13
2014,37,Ontario,60,0.15,6,1,0,52,10
2014,38,Ontario,53,0.02,4,0,1,56,7
2014,39,Ontario,60,0.08,4,0,0,56,3
2014,40,Ontario,61,0.06,4,0,0,56,6
2014,41,Ontario,50,0.06,6,0,0,56,4
2013,17,Ontario,43,0.05,6,0,0,0,2
2013,18,Ontario,57,0.05,6,0,0,0,3
2013,19,Ontario,59,0.04,5,0,0,0,4
2013,20,Ontario,51,0.02,8,0,0,0,3
2013,21,Ontario,60,0.17,8,0,0,0,7
2013,22,Ontario,64,0.16,6,1,0,0,9
2013,23,Ontario,58,0.05,7,1,0,0,9
2013,24,Ontario,64,0.29,6,0,0,0,12
2013,25,Ontario,64,0.11,5,0,0,0,12
2013,26,Ontario,73,0.06,4,0,1,2,12
2013,27,Ontario,71,0.05,5,1,0,2,20
2013,28,Ontario,72,0.13,6,2,0,4,15
2013,29,Ontario,80,0.05,5,1,2,12,20
2013,30,Ontario,65,0.12,6,5,0,22,56
2013,31,Ontario,66,0.26,5,4,8,41,43
2013,32,Ontario,67,0.04,6,5,6,65,32
2013,33,Ontario,63,0,5,5,2,89,24
2013,34,Ontario,70,0,5,2,0,131,30
2013,35,Ontario,72,0.2,3,2,8,155,22
2013,36,Ontario,63,0.12,6,7,2,179,12
2013,37,Ontario,64,0.04,6,3,2,190,15
2013,38,Ontario,57,0.17,4,5,2,194,9
2013,39,Ontario,55,0,4,0,1,196,5
2013,40,Ontario,61,0.04,4,5,0,198,9
2013,41,Ontario,56,0.04,4,1,0,198,4
2012,17,Ontario,40,0.06,11,0,0,0,4
2012,18,Ontario,50,0.12,6,0,0,0,3
2012,19,Ontario,56,0.07,6,0,0,0,3
2012,20,Ontario,58,0.02,4,0,0,0,3
2012,21,Ontario,69,0.01,6,0,0,0,5
2012,22,Ontario,64,0.09,8,0,0,0,3
2012,23,Ontario,63,0.03,6,1,0,0,6
2012,24,Ontario,67,0.08,6,0,0,0,4
2012,25,Ontario,76,0.17,6,0,0,2,7
2012,26,Ontario,70,0.04,7,0,0,6,10
2012,27,Ontario,75,0.04,5,3,1,10,39
2012,28,Ontario,73,0.02,5,5,3,19,24
2012,29,Ontario,75,0.06,6,9,1,30,19
2012,30,Ontario,72,0.38,6,14,2,89,17
2012,31,Ontario,73,0.16,4,23,1,162,77
2012,32,Ontario,70,0.14,6,44,1,249,46
2012,33,Ontario,68,0.05,4,44,8,312,64
2012,34,Ontario,67,0,4,38,4,375,83
2012,35,Ontario,70,0.15,6,26,0,409,100
2012,36,Ontario,69,0.56,4,25,0,434,79
2012,37,Ontario,61,0.03,5,17,2,454,37
2012,38,Ontario,57,0.16,5,3,4,462,23
2012,39,Ontario,53,0,6,2,6,462,24
2012,40,Ontario,57,0.03,5,3,0,464,18
2012,41,Ontario,42,0.04,5,1,0,464,10
2015,17,Saskatchewan,50,0,10,0,0,0,6
2015,18,Saskatchewan,46,0,11,0,0,0,12
2015,19,Saskatchewan,46,0,9,0,0,0,6
2015,20,Saskatchewan,53,0,8,0,0,0,6
2015,21,Saskatchewan,56,0,8,0,0,2,9
2015,22,Saskatchewan,60,0,10,0,0,0,9
2015,23,Saskatchewan,64,0,10,0,0,3,9
2015,24,Saskatchewan,57,0,8,0,0,3,12
2015,25,Saskatchewan,65,0,7,0,0,10,31
2015,26,Saskatchewan,70,0,6,0,0,13,15
2015,27,Saskatchewan,66,0,9,0,0,16,13
2015,28,Saskatchewan,67,0,8,0,0,40,15
2015,29,Saskatchewan,68,0,10,0,0,47,16
2015,30,Saskatchewan,63,0.02,9,0,0,69,43
2015,31,Saskatchewan,63,0,8,0,0,67,16
2015,32,Saskatchewan,70,0,8,0,0,80,28
2015,33,Saskatchewan,58,0,8,0,0,94,38
2015,34,Saskatchewan,62,0,8,0,0,42,21
2015,35,Saskatchewan,61,0,10,0,1,41,14
2015,36,Saskatchewan,53,0,8,0,0,0,9
2015,37,Saskatchewan,52,0,8,0,0,0,5
2015,38,Saskatchewan,54,0,10,0,0,0,5
2015,39,Saskatchewan,48,0,8,0,0,0,5
2015,40,Saskatchewan,48,0,9,0,0,0,8
2015,41,Saskatchewan,44,0,11,0,0,0,5
2014,17,Saskatchewan,40,0,12,0,0,0,6
2014,18,Saskatchewan,41,0,10,0,0,0,6
2014,19,Saskatchewan,41,0,9,0,0,0,6
2014,20,Saskatchewan,45,0,7,0,0,0,6
2014,21,Saskatchewan,59,0,10,0,0,0,13
2014,22,Saskatchewan,57,0,11,0,0,0,20
2014,23,Saskatchewan,55,0,8,0,0,0,17
2014,24,Saskatchewan,53,0,10,0,0,0,13
2014,25,Saskatchewan,57,0,10,0,0,0,7
2014,26,Saskatchewan,63,0,8,0,0,0,21
2014,27,Saskatchewan,66,0,11,0,0,0,26
2014,28,Saskatchewan,65,0,10,0,0,0,69
2014,29,Saskatchewan,64,0,9,0,0,0,65
2014,30,Saskatchewan,63,0,9,0,0,1,60
2014,31,Saskatchewan,67,0,6,0,0,1,36
2014,32,Saskatchewan,69,0,6,0,2,2,47
2014,33,Saskatchewan,67,0,7,0,0,9,67
2014,34,Saskatchewan,64,0,8,0,0,19,45
2014,35,Saskatchewan,58,0,9,0,0,20,34
2014,36,Saskatchewan,56,0,8,0,0,20,13
2014,37,Saskatchewan,46,0,9,0,0,20,19
2014,38,Saskatchewan,55,0,8,0,0,20,6
2014,39,Saskatchewan,61,0,9,0,0,20,16
2014,40,Saskatchewan,44,0,12,0,0,20,12
2014,41,Saskatchewan,45,0,9,0,0,20,6
2013,17,Saskatchewan,34,0,10,0,0,0,10
2013,18,Saskatchewan,40,0,12,0,0,0,14
2013,19,Saskatchewan,50,0,12,0,0,0,14
2013,20,Saskatchewan,59,0,9,0,0,0,7
2013,21,Saskatchewan,57,0,13,0,0,0,7
2013,22,Saskatchewan,60,0,9,0,0,0,14
2013,23,Saskatchewan,57,0,9,0,0,0,21
2013,24,Saskatchewan,57,0,10,0,0,0,20
2013,25,Saskatchewan,61,0,10,0,0,0,14
2013,26,Saskatchewan,64,0,7,0,0,0,41
2013,27,Saskatchewan,69,0,7,0,0,0,61
2013,28,Saskatchewan,65,0,8,0,0,1,65
2013,29,Saskatchewan,62,0,9,0,3,1,81
2013,30,Saskatchewan,60,0,9,0,1,3,75
2013,31,Saskatchewan,59,0,8,0,2,3,33
2013,32,Saskatchewan,60,0,6,0,1,18,44
2013,33,Saskatchewan,69,0,8,0,0,29,75
2013,34,Saskatchewan,66,0,8,1,1,29,60
2013,35,Saskatchewan,69,0,8,3,0,36,24
2013,36,Saskatchewan,67,0,7,1,0,40,21
2013,37,Saskatchewan,62,0,9,0,0,40,26
2013,38,Saskatchewan,57,0,10,1,2,40,32
2013,39,Saskatchewan,51,0,9,0,1,40,13
2013,40,Saskatchewan,45,0,11,0,0,40,29
2013,41,Saskatchewan,46,0,10,0,0,40,10
2012,17,Saskatchewan,44,0,13,0,0,0,24
2012,18,Saskatchewan,46,0,12,0,0,0,16
2012,19,Saskatchewan,51,0,13,0,0,0,16
2012,20,Saskatchewan,54,0,12,0,0,0,9
2012,21,Saskatchewan,48,0,11,0,0,0,17
2012,22,Saskatchewan,53,0,9,0,0,0,16
2012,23,Saskatchewan,61,0,13,0,0,0,8
2012,24,Saskatchewan,56,0,11,0,0,0,16
2012,25,Saskatchewan,58,0,7,0,0,0,25
2012,26,Saskatchewan,64,0,12,0,0,0,22
2012,27,Saskatchewan,65,0,9,0,0,0,23
2012,28,Saskatchewan,71,0,7,0,1,0,67
2012,29,Saskatchewan,67,0,10,0,0,0,34
2012,30,Saskatchewan,67,0,8,0,0,0,28
2012,31,Saskatchewan,64,0,8,0,0,0,59
2012,32,Saskatchewan,68,0,8,0,0,3,58
2012,33,Saskatchewan,59,0,8,2,0,4,34
2012,34,Saskatchewan,65,0,9,1,0,6,100
2012,35,Saskatchewan,64,0,9,0,0,6,49
2012,36,Saskatchewan,55,0,11,3,0,6,41
2012,37,Saskatchewan,58,0,13,0,0,6,16
2012,38,Saskatchewan,50,0,8,3,0,6,19
2012,39,Saskatchewan,55,0,6,0,0,6,15
2012,40,Saskatchewan,42,0,10,0,0,6,11
2012,41,Saskatchewan,36,0,8,0,0,6,7
```

First I produced this plot

[image]

But I did that in the most brute force way imaginable

```
#split out each year
cases2015 <- subset(mosquitoes, mosquitoes$Years==2015)
cases2014 <- subset(mosquitoes, mosquitoes$Years==2014)
cases2013 <- subset(mosquitoes, mosquitoes$Years==2013)
cases2012 <- subset(mosquitoes, mosquitoes$Years==2012)

#get the sums by week
aggregate2015 <- aggregate(cases2015$Number.of.cases, by=list(Weeks=cases2015$Weeks), FUN=sum)
aggregate2014 <- aggregate(cases2014$Number.of.cases, by=list(Weeks=cases2014$Weeks), FUN=sum)
aggregate2013 <- aggregate(cases2013$Number.of.cases, by=list(Weeks=cases2013$Weeks), FUN=sum)
aggregate2012 <- aggregate(cases2012$Number.of.cases, by=list(Weeks=cases2012$Weeks), FUN=sum)

#put the sums back together into a dataframe
aggregateSums <- aggregate2012
aggregateSums <- cbind(aggregateSums, aggregate2013[,2])
aggregateSums <- cbind(aggregateSums, aggregate2014[,2])
aggregateSums <- cbind(aggregateSums, aggregate2015[,2])

#give the columns useful names
colnames(aggregateSums) <- c("Weeks","Cases.2012","Cases.2013","Cases.2014","Cases.2015")

#base R plot
#plot the first set of points
plot(x=aggregateSums$Weeks,y=aggregateSums$Cases.2012,pch=16,col="Red",main="West Nile Cases",xlab="Week",ylab="Number of Cases")

#add additional years
points(x=aggregateSums$Weeks,y=aggregateSums$Cases.2013,pch=15,col="Blue")
points(x=aggregateSums$Weeks,y=aggregateSums$Cases.2014,pch=14,col="Orange")
points(x=aggregateSums$Weeks,y=aggregateSums$Cases.2015,pch=13,col="Brown")

#add the connecting lines
lines(x=aggregateSums$Weeks,y=aggregateSums$Cases.2012,col="Red")
lines(x=aggregateSums$Weeks,y=aggregateSums$Cases.2013,col="Blue")
lines(x=aggregateSums$Weeks,y=aggregateSums$Cases.2014,col="Orange")
lines(x=aggregateSums$Weeks,y=aggregateSums$Cases.2015,col="Brown")

#click to place legend
legend(locator(1),c("2012","2013","2014","2015"),pch=c(16,15,14,13), col=c("Red","Blue","Orange","Brown"))
```

So surely there has to be a more efficient way to get there.

My next step is to produce the same plot but for just one province at a time.  I don't want to have to go through the above 6 times...

I'm opening to accomplishing this via ggplot.  If possible, I'd like to do it without resorting to additional packages (like plyr) as I'm trying to learn the base functionality for manipulating data.

Just to close the loop after Biranjan's answer...

```
mosq2 <- mosquitoes %>% 
         select(Years,Weeks,Province,Number.of.cases) %>% 
         group_by(Years,Weeks,Province) %>% 
         summarise(sum_case=sum(Number.of.cases))

ggplot(data=mosq2, aes(x=as.factor(Weeks),y=sum_case,color=as.factor(Years))) + 
            geom_point(aes(shape=as.factor(Years))) + 
            geom_line(aes(group=as.factor(Years))) + 
            labs(title="West Nile Cases", x="weeks", y="Number of cases") +
            theme(legend.title=element_blank()) +
            facet_wrap(~Province,ncol=3) +
            scale_x_discrete(breaks=c(17,30,41))
```

Turned out quite nicely

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ggplot(data=data1, aes(x=as.factor(Weeks),y=sum_case,color=as.factor(Years)))+
geom_point(aes(shape=as.factor(Years)))+
geom_line(aes(group=as.factor(Years)))+
labs(title="West Nile cases",x="weeks",y="Number of cases")+
theme(legend.title=element_blank())
```

Update:
I had too few points in my simulation so it rendered fine so that was the problem. I could't find a way to plot just using ggplot. The same code works if  "dplyr" is used first and variable name edited accordingly. I know it is not what you are looking for, sorry to disappoint you.

```
library(dplyr)
data1 <- data %>%
    select(Years,Weeks,Number.of.cases) %>%
    group_by(Years,Weeks) %>%
    summarise(sum_case=sum(Number.of.cases))
```

Comment: I edited the OP to include the entire data set...thought it might have been too large initially.  I used your code and updated the names to match my column headings and got something else...

Comment: Not disappointed!  You got me on track to produce a facet_wrap'ed plot and it turned out nicely.